# Eclipse Error : open git-upload-pack and not authorized (EGit)

Tags: eclipse, exception, proxy, egit, jgit

I have seen this problem here often but my problem seems to be more complex. I am not able to clone and use marketplace at the same time. I have to switch between Native and Manual Settings.
Here The diffrence between my Proxy Settings:

Manual:

1. Cloning ist not working
2. Internal Internet Browser ist Working
3. Marketplace is working

When i add this to the eclipse.ini

```
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4
```

It is this exception:

```
  org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: https://XXX.XXX.XXX/scm/Test/testprof.git: cannot open git-upload-pack
            at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.execute(LsRemoteCommand.java:221)
            at org.eclipse.jgit.api.LsRemoteCommand.call(LsRemoteCommand.java:159)
            at org.eclipse.egit.core.op.ListRemoteOperation.run(ListRemoteOperation.java:100)
            at org.eclipse.egit.ui.internal.clone.SourceBranchPage$8.run(SourceBranchPage.java:341)
            at org.eclipse.jface.operation.ModalContext$ModalContextThread.run(ModalContext.java:119)
```

and without it:

```
java.lang.Exception: org.eclipse.jgit.api.errors.TransportException: https://XXX.XX.XX/scm/XXX/XXX.git: not authorized
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.git.impl.GitCloneTaskImpl.perform(GitCloneTaskImpl.java:882)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.doPerformNeededSetupTasks(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3305)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer.access$1(SetupTaskPerformer.java:3248)
  at org.eclipse.oomph.setup.internal.core.SetupTaskPerformer$WorkspaceUtil$1.run(SetupTaskPerformer.java:4469)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2240)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.resources.Workspace.run(Workspace.java:2267)
```

Native:

1. Cloning is working
2. Internal Brwoser is working
3. Marketplace is not working

When i add this to the eclipse.ini

```
-Dorg.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.excludeContributors=org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient4
```

this happens:

```
org.eclipse.core.runtime.CoreException: Cannot install remote marketplace locations: Connection failed

    This is most often caused by a problem with your internet connection. Please check your internet connection and retry.

        at org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.ui.commands.MarketplaceWizardCommand.execute(MarketplaceWizardCommand.java:106)

        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.HandlerProxy.execute(HandlerProxy.java:295)

        at org.eclipse.ui.internal.handlers.E4HandlerProxy.execute(E4HandlerProxy.java:90)

        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)

        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)

        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)

    and without it:

        Failed to stream using org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.transport.httpclient.HttpClientTransport@1e8c67f7 - falling back to org.eclipse.epp.internal.mpc.core.util.TransportFactory$1@7592008d: Connection failed
        This is most often caused by a problem with your internet connection. Please check your internet connection and retry.
```

Some information:

Yes, my credentials are correct.

Yes, my Proxy settings are correct

ssl.verify in git configs is =false

Windows 7

Egit version 4.4.1 (I also tried 4.6)

Cloning outside of Eclipse is working too

Thanks for your help... if i miss some information please ask...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Solution ist to Clear the HTTPS field in the Network Settings and switch back to Manual.
Marketplace works and Cloning.